# Is the sentence "Queueing is so thoughtful of you." grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality, adjectives, gerunds, tough-movement

In the following two blog posts ("[Illiteracy in Singapore - the Land Transport Authority](http://vivitelaeti.blogspot.sg/2016/09/illiteracy-in-singapore-land-transport.html)" and "[LTA's illiterate poster](http://vivitelaeti.blogspot.sg/2017/04/ltas-illiterate-poster.html)") the author accused the poster depicted below of being evidence of illiteracy in Singapore, which I take to mean that there's something grammatically incorrect with it. How so?

The second post actually includes a bit of a response to this question, but his explanation is quite confusing. The blog poster said it had nothing to do with the singular verb, or "the issue of concord" in his words.

Anyone knowledgeable enough about grammar to decode this chunk of text?

> What makes the sentence ungrammatical is its utter meaninglessness. Since the copulative verb links the subject and the subject complement, the introduction of an unrelated clause in lieu of the subject complement renders the sentence an absurdity that has no meaning. One cannot ignore the grammatical function of the copula, The addition of a prop or dummy subject is of course one possibility that is available to a writer in a sea of possible variations.

[image: "Queuing and giving way to alighting passengers is so thoughtful of you. Nice work!" is displayed on a billboard. Below it is the hashtag "#GiveWayGlenda" and the words "Land Transport Authority: We Keep Your World Moving". Above it are the words "Thoughtfulness: A Better Ride for You & Me"]

Comment: Nothing ungrammatical about  that sentence.

Comment: Maybe the author doesn't like queues and prefers waiting in line... https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/84440/us-and-uk-english-queue-or-wait-in-line and https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/321044/is-it-conceivable-that-president-obama-might-use-the-word-queue/321047#321047

Comment: Maybe he thinks "is" should be "are", since queuing and giving way to alighting passengers are two separate acts. But the poster could intend it as a combined action, then it's singular.

Comment: It looks like the poster is simply quoting a tweet. No one really expects proper grammar in tweets, they're very informal.

Comment: Seeing the blog poster mentions "Alan and George works as a team" as another mistake, I _assume_ they are referring to the idea that _is_ should be _are_ on this poster. But as @Barmar stated, it seems absolutely fine in this case. A simple case of a good bark up a wrong tree?

Comment: @Barmar even if queing and giving way are two seperate actions (which I think they are), we can still say "is", as we're referring to the **general behaviour of the reader** - a singular thing which encompasses various actual physical behaviours. It's like saying "It is nice of you to do these things".   The alternative of "are" just seems horribly wrong to me: "Queueing and giving way to alighting passengers are so nice of you".

Comment: @Max Williams I agree totally. This is what makes notional agreement so tricky. What is the deep structure? [The standard practice you display –] queuing and giving way to alighting passengers [–] is so thoughtful of you. (?) You can see why they use the deleted version.

Comment: @MaxWilliams There are many questions here about the proper verb agrement when dealing with "X and Y" references. The right answer is very dependent on the specifics, and sometimes it can go either way.

Comment: @Barmar I agree, language isn't always consistent!

Comment: @EdwinAshworth once you put it like that (which is the correct analysis I think), I noticed that it would be better (I think) without "of you" at the end.

Comment: @Max Williams (oops, I can't notify everyone D: Hope others still see this though) Hi guys, thanks for the responses! I myself didn't see anything wrong with the sentence, but was curious why the poster thought there was a mistake. I read some of his other posts and apparently he made a response  (included in edit above) specifically about this. His explanation was very confusing though.

Comment: @Barmar what's interesting is that the blog poster said it had nothing to do with the singular verb, or "the issue of concord" in his words

Comment: To be thoughtful of you is an idiomatic expression! Arriving on time for dinner is thoughtful of you.  The explanation is: this is an idiom.

Comment: @Lambie: "It is/was thoughtful of you to arrive on time for dinner" would certainly be idiomatic. But does "Arriving on time for dinner is thoughtful of you" really seem perfectly idiomatic to you? I was only able to find one similar example in the Google Books corpus (that is, of "is thoughtful of you" not followed by a *to*-infinitive, and preceded by a subject other than "it", "that" or "this") and it sounds questionable to me:

Comment: @sumelic, Absolutely.  You can put the "is thoughtful of [name or pronoun] at the end, of course. I go to my own knowledge here. If I had to rely on google books, I'd be finished. Responding to me was thoughtful of you. I appreciate it. :)

Comment: "What makes the sentence ungrammatical is its utter meaninglessness." Well, this is entirely wrong, notwithstanding that the sentence is completely meaningful. A sentence can be grammatical but nonsensical, take the classic *Colorless green ideas sleep furiously.*

Comment: Surprised I haven't seen this post on Reddit's /r/iamverysmart

Comment: Yes, it's entirely grammatical. 'NP is AdjP' - Running is dangerous. Queuing is thoughtful. It means that it is thoughtful to stand in a line (instead of mobbing the ticket taker: mobbing is rude).

Comment: @sumelic Thank you for all the research you've done and taking an interest in this question! Nice of you to list so many examples where 'wise-type' adjectives are used. From this POV, the sentence does sound a little strange though I saw nothing wrong with it at first.  to all: I really wasn't expecting so many detailed responses when I came back to check on it. It is all very interesting and thought-provoking, and I see both perspectives of why the sentence may be correct or wrong

Comment: I also have to say sorry for my absence from this discussion as the OP >< as I've been a little busy the past week

Answer (score 8):

Nothing wrong with that sentence, 'Queueing' here is a gerund, essentially a noun.

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/gerund

Answer (score 4):

I would somewhat tentatively say that the sentence on the sign is grammatical. My own intuitions don't seem to give an entirely clear answer, but other people's intuitions and usage seem to support this kind of sentence.

I think the objection to the sentence "Queueing is so thoughtful of you" is based on an objection to the use of the structure "[verb]ing is (so) [adjective] of [someone]" to express the idea "It is (so) [adjective] of [someone] to [verb]". The structure starting with a gerund does seem to be grammatical according to the judgements of at least one linguist, but it sounded a little strange to me when I first thought about the sentence in your question, so it may not feel entirely natural for all English speakers. ("Queueing is so thoughtful" sounds OK to me. So it seems to me that the issue, if there is one, would be with the use of the prepositional phrase "of you" after "thoughtful" in this context.)

I found the following apparently parallel examples marked as grammatical in *Adjectives and adjective complement constructions in English,* a dissertation by Arlene Berman (1973):

> (28) a. Burning the papers was clever of you
>   
>     b. Bringing wine was thoughtful of Mary
>   
>     c. Continuing to harp on the subject was wrong of you

(p 230)

### "*Wise*-type adjectives" (like "wise of you")

I was led to Berman's dissertation because it was referenced in a paper specifically about the class of adjectives that behave like this: "[*Wise*-type Adjective Constructions and the Uniformity Condition](https://ir.kochi-u.ac.jp/dspace/bitstream/10126/1545/1/H036-02.pdf)", by Shin Oshima. I wasn't able to find any examples in Oshima's paper that seemed directly relevant to your question, but it has some useful terminology and examples of other constructions that make use of adjectives like this.

### Berman's judgements of related constructions

I think to understand Berman's examples better, it will help to look at some of the other things she says about this type of adjective. Actually, Berman's section on adjectives with *of*-NP complements starts out with examples of extraposed sentences of the type that I feel entirely comfortable with (and that I assume any English speaker would feel entirely comfortable with):

> (24) a. It was clever of you to burn the papers
>   
>     b. It was thoughtful of Mary to bring wine
>   
>     c. It was wrong of you to continue harping on the subject

(p. 229)

Berman points out that sentences like "*It was clever of Max for his sister to do that" and "*It was clever of Max for him to do that" are not grammatical (p. 229). (However, note that Oshima says the latter construction may be possible in some dialects.)

Berman also judges the following sentences unacceptable::

> (27) a. *To burn the papers was clever of you
>   
>     b. *To bring wine was thoughtful of Mary
>   
>     c. *To keep harping on the subject was wrong of you

(28 is the acceptability judgements given above for sentences starting with a gerund)

> (29) a. *It was clever of you burning the papers
>   
>     b. *It was thoughtful of Mary bringing wine
>   
>     c. *It was wrong of you continuing to harp on the subject

and suggests that "It seems reasonable to assume that sentences like (28) are derived from sentences like (27), when Extraposition fails to apply.<sup>5</sup>" (p. 230).

Endnote 5 says:

> This sort of alternation seems to exist more generally. I find, for example, the following:
>
> > (i) It was easy for Joe to do that
> >     
> > (ii) *To do that was easy for Joe
> >     
> > (iii) Doing that was easy for Joe
>
> Bare infinitives in subject position seem to be quite restricted, although they are not wholly impossible. I have not examined the conditions under which they are and are not acceptable.

(p. 252)

I agree with Berman that bare infinitives are not wholly impossible as subjects. I'm not sure that I agree with her judgement that "To do that was easy for Joe" is unacceptable.

Berman also lists a few restrictions that seem to her to apply to this kind of adjective. The first of the following restrictions seems more obviously correct to me than the second. Berman notes that

> While other subject-embedding adjectives allow the noun phrases in their prepositional complement to be questioned and relativized, this is not possible with sentences like (24):
>
> > (37) a. To whom is it clear that Max is wrong
> >     
> >     b. the man to whom it is clear that Max was wrong
> >     
> > (38) a. For whom is it easy to write a dissertation 
> >     
> >     b. the man for whom it is easy to write a dissertation
> >     
> > (39) a. *Of whom was it stupid to do that
> >     
> >     b. *the man of whom it was stupid to do that

(p 233)

Berman has no explanation for these acceptability judgements, but I fully agree with them.

The next judgement seems more iffy to me: Berman feels that

> adjectives with of-NP complements do not allow Tough-movement:
>
> > (40) a. *That document was careless of Jeb to burn
> >     
> >     b. *That was stupid of you to do

(p 233)

I don't feel certain that these sentences are grammatical for me, but "That was stupid of you to do" doesn't immediately seem unacceptable to me either. I found an example of it on the Internet (I don't know if it was written by a native English speaker):

> The pisces men I know/knew (March 13-18th babies) are all fragile ego, sensitive as shit dudes. Don't tell him he's not behaving like a man, his brows look bushy in a picture, **that was stupid of you to do** because then his whole ego is thrown off; he doesn't wanna play anymore and he's taking his ball home with him.

(comment by Peachyvision, Apr 30, 2015; #18 in the thread "[So do pisces men like to get cussed out and called names?](https://www.lipstickalley.com/threads/so-do-pisces-men-like-to-get-cussed-out-and-called-names.866985/)", discussion in 'The Lipstick Alley Psychic Hotline' started by StayMadBishes, Apr 30, 2015)

### Contexts where it sounds OK to me to use a "*wise*-type adjective" without a following *to*-infinitive

For me, "[adjective] of you" definitely works without a following *to*-infinitive when the subject is one of the following pronouns:

- *this* or *that* (singular demonstratives)
- *which* (as a singular inanimate relative pronoun)

Examples:

- "**That** wasn't very nice of you."
- "**This** is so thoughtful of you!"
- "He helped me with my errands, **which** was thoughtful of him."

(It also sounds fine to me to use a quantifier before one of these pronouns, as in "**All of this** is very thoughtful of you.")

And it also sounds fine in exclamatory sentences with "How" at the start (I don't know enough syntax to know how these work):

- "**How silly** of me."

(In some cases, at least when there is a *to*-infinitive, the "how" can be left out in similar sentences: "How stupid of them to leave it behind!" "Silly of me to forget about that.")

(Also, I don't know if these could be taken to be short versions of "How silly of me *that was*" or "How silly (?*it was*) of me *to do that*")

### Other examples I have found of *wise*-type adjectives used without a *to*-infinitive (taken from the Internet)

- I was able to find "worrying was silly of me" used in a blog post by someone who appears to be a native English speaker: "[Internship Assignment A](https://keepcalmandstudyabroadblog.wordpress.com/2016/09/14/internship-assignment-a/)", *Keep Calm and Study Abroad.*
- "[Everything you say about my time with Wade is thoughtful of you](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZGgMQqaaU18C&pg=PA123&dq=%22is%20thoughtful%20of%20you%22%20-%22that%20is%20thoughtful%20of%20you%22%20-%22it%20is%20thoughtful%20of%20you%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjqqPfv0KLWAhXl7IMKHRzFBiMQ6AEIMTAC#v=onepage&q=%22is%20thoughtful%20of%20you%22%20-%22that%20is%20thoughtful%20of%20you%22%20-%22it%20is%20thoughtful%20of%20you%22&f=false)" (This was the only example of "is thoughtful of you" that I found on Google Books that didn't have "it", "this" or "that" as the subject)
- From Google as a whole (not Google Books) there are few more examples with a gerund:

  - "[I understand you desire to try something to save the birds, putting a a bell on her for that reason is thoughtful of you](https://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070925112738AAk8KcT)"
  - "[Being vague about a plot thats well know in the novel is thoughtful of you, even though theres no plot beyond what you describe](https://dtmmr.com/2015/11/12/room-2015/)"
  - "[Considering her feelings is thoughtful of you, but if it's truly the latter situation, go stay with your Dad until she realizes she needs to grow up and...](http://www.experienceproject.com/question-answer/I-Want-To-Live-With-My-Dad-But-My-Mum-Always-Uses-Emotional-Blackmail-What-Do-I-Do/18189)"
- and from Google, a few with other nouns as the subject:

  - "[Very heartfelt, Willis, and the PS is thoughtful of you.](https://wattsupwiththat.com/2013/02/14/even-scientists-need-love/)"
  - "[Editing is amazing and the music selection is thoughtful of you.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OBeyXyanrA0)"

With a plural verb:

- "[The flowers **are very thoughtful of you**](https://www.librarything.com/topic/162845)."
- "[The feelings you described regarding entrapment and suffocation **are very perceptive of you**](http://textura.org/archives/interviews/fivequestions_mcencroe.htm)." (This one sounds very strange to me; it's from an interview, so it probably was spoken spontaneously)
- "I know these things **are silly of me to feel.**" (From some Instagram post; this one also sounds strange to me)

John Lawler's answer to *[How does the to infinitive work with adjectives like “wrong” and “wise”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/327469/77227)* provides the example

> For me to go home that day was wise (of me).

where the infinitive precedes rather than follows, but I don't know if that is intended to be a grammatical example sentence, or just an ungrammatical illustration of the theorized underlying structure of "It was wise of me to go home that day." (Another example is "It was wise (of me) (for me) to go home that day", which as I mentioned above is ungrammatical for most speakers when both "of me" and "for me" are included.)

### Lists of "wise-type" adjectives

Berman gives a short list of adjectives that take of-NP complements: *clever, stupid, idiotic, careless, wrong, brilliant, kind, nice, thoughtful* (from (23), on p. 229).

Oshima mentions most of these, as well as a few more like *foolish, good, wise* (from (1), on p. 12).

I found another source that mentions "wise-type" adjectives, the SAL Taxonomy for English Adjectives, but none of the related texts that I found mention the "V-ing is [adjective] of [N]" structure specifically:

- [SAL Taxonomy for English Adjectives](http://www.logosinstitute.org/learnlogos/SALTaxonomy/SAL_ADJS.pdf) (PDF)
- [SAL Adjective Narratives](http://www.l2f.inesc-id.pt/~abarreiro/openlogos-tutorial/SADJnarr.htm)

  This resource lists a number of other adjectives that act like "wise" and "thoughtful": *audacious, astute, bestial, bold, brilliant, careless, childish, discriminatory, early, far-sighted, heroic, humane, impudent, intelligent, late, negligent, noble, perceptive, polite, provocative, reckless, rude, shrewd, undiplomatic, unprincipled*

### Works Cited

Berman, Arlene (1973). "Adjectives and Adjective Complement Con-      structions in English.” Ph.D. dissertation, Harvard.

Oshima, Shin (1987). *Wise*-type Adjective Constructions and the Uniformity Condition." Kochi University Academic Research Report 36, Humanities

Comment: Answer scores need interchanging.

Answer (score 1):

You have asked a thought-provoking question that shows your objective consideration of the author's opinions.

Although I am not at all well-versed with the technical terms that infest that author's paragraph, I am willing to interpret it as an objection to the use of a noun-clause "queuing and giving way to alighting passengers"  as a subject, which he calls 'unrelated' because nowhere does it refer to the **actual subject 'you'** -- which is probably an overly pedantic opinion.

A crude and simple breakdown of the quoted sentence in its full form (not extracting the gerund 'queueing' out of its clause)  would be [correct me if I am wrong]:

> subject = queuing and giving way to alighting passengers (noun clause)
>
> verb =  is (linking verb)
>
> object [more accurately, a 'state of being' because of the use of a [linking verb](https://www.englishgrammar101.com/module-3/verbs/lesson-3/linking-verbs)] = so thoughtful of you.

What's not to like? It does not seem to be ungrammatical.

I assume that the most technically correct form of the sentence would be

> It is so thoughtful of **you** *to be* queueing and giving way to alighting passengers.

The sentence in question is is just a simple reversal of this  order:

> (to be) queueing and giving way to alighting passengers is so thoughtful of you

and that by itself proves it is grammatical, the 'to be' having been dropped because implied and redundant --  but the author possibly thinks it is *more correct* [grammatical but non-standard, and sometimes an awkward construction] to say something that includes some form of 'you' in the subject clause, as for example:

> **Your** queueing and giving way to alighting passengers is so thoughtful (of you)

which would certainly  avoid his pernicious if possibly technically correct accusation of 'unrelated clause': this is the type of sentence construction sometimes chosen by non-native speakers or in dialects like Indian English and Singapore English, and possibly reflects the syntax of regional languages. **The author seems determined that some form of or reference to 'you' should appear in the noun clause to avoid any suspicion of illiteracy**, but any native speaker of English here at ELU will tell you that the 'your' can be acceptably dropped in common usage to say

> Queueing and giving way to alighting passengers is so thoughtful of you.

Calling it illiteracy is a very excessive objection IMHO.

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer! I didn't try too hard to understand the use of the technical terms in the quoted paragraph because to me, it sounded like the author was bloviating to avoid admitting ignorance :) Your interpretation of what he meant by "unrelated clause" seems plausible. "Your queueing and giving way to alighting passengers is so thoughtful of you" is not quite a reversal of "It is so thoughtful of you to be queueing and giving way to alighting passengers." You've dropped the "to be", and adding the "your" creates an odd sense of redundancy in my opinion.

Comment: "Your queueing and giving way to alighting passengers is so thoughtful" seems grammatical to me, but having "of you" at the end still sounds odd to me.

Comment: This is the type of sentence construction sometimes chosen by non-native speakers or in dialects like Indian English and Singapore English, @sumelic. It possibly reflects the syntax of regional languages. The author seems determined that some form of 'you' should appear in the noun clause to avoid illiteracy. Hence 'your' has been used awkwardly to reflect the meaning of 'to be' -- as you know, it is quite unnecessary to do all of that and I have now edited this comment into my answer.

Comment: You are right about the reversal of order -- now improved the answer and examples based on your comments, @sumelic.

Comment: To my ear, the most natural sentence (I hesitate to say most *grammatical*) would be something like "It is so thoughtful of you *to queue and give way*; I believe the to-infinitive is more commonly used after an adjective than the continuous infinitive. This form of the sentence reminds me of [Eliza Doolittle's practice sentence, "How kind of you to let me come."](https://youtu.be/MJr9SSJKkII?t=3m10s)

Comment: *"It is so thoughtful of you to queue and give way"* -- that is indeed most natural *and* grammatical @1006a -- I was giving the grammatically correct version of the specific sentence structure quoted by OP.

Comment: I don't think you have to stick with the -ing form of the verb to "match" the sentence structure, though; when the infinitive and gerund are interchangeable (obviously they aren't always), it's the plain to-infinitive that is used, e.g. "I like learning" = "I like to learn" not *"I like to be learning".

Comment: Good point -- thanks for reminding me, @1006a!

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is upbeat and friendly and grammatically correct. Compared to what I have seen in other Asian countries like misspelled English words on the backs of tee shirts and spelling and grammatical errors on instruction and safety signs, this billboard is written rather well. However, you said that one author accused the LTA of contributing to illiteracy in Singapore.

The reason it is difficult to understand what he is saying in his blog is that he is being too vague. From my understanding, he is talking about the link between the first part of the sentence, 'queueing and giving way to passengers' and the second part of the sentence, 'thoughtful of you', joined together by the copula (linking verb) 'is'. The first issue he has is not with the grammar, but with word choice. Thoughtful should be replaced with mindful.

thoughtful - absorbed in or involving thought

mindful - conscious or aware of something

We use thoughtful to described a situation where someone goes out of his way to do something in consideration of the feelings of others. We use mindful in a situation where someone is observing the rules or watching his manners. Therefore, because the LTA is addressing the need to observe the rules when getting on or off the train, 'mindful' is the appropriate choice and 'thoughtful' gives us that uneasy feeling that something is not quite right with the sentence, even if we understand what the LTA is trying to say.

Unfortunately, the blog writer is not only obscure in his meaning, but he also makes poor word choices as well, detracting from what otherwise would be a good point that he is making. First, he says that the sentence is meaningless, despite the fact that we clearly understand what the LTA means. What he intends to say is that writer choses a word with a meaning that does not fit the second half of the sentence. A thoughtful person does not queue or give way. A mindful person queues and gives way. Being thoughtful and giving way are unrelated in the opinion of the blogger.

Secondly, he talks about using a prop or dummy subject. He is suggesting that the sentence is written in an awkward manner and needs reworking, but from what I can tell in the short block of text posted above, he does not go into further explanation or give an example of how he thinks the LTA's message should be written. But I think he means that the subject should go at the beginning of the sentence, so that it reads:

'You are being thoughtful when you queue and give way to alighting passengers.'

When it is written as 'Queueing and giving way is...', 'queueing' and 'giving way' are gerunds acting as the subjects, but the real subject is 'you', while 'queueing' and 'giving way' are props or fakes, holding the place of the subject in the sentence.

The blogger is suggesting that in order to keep the integrity of the English language, it is important to teach learners of English as a second language the appropriate usage and meaning of words. It is also necessary to be mindful poorly written sentences. When displaying improper use of English publicly, rather than improve its citizens' English ability, the Singaporean government causes problems with learning English correctly. This is what the blogger refers to when he talks about illiteracy because ESL learners will, in turn, write poorly as a result.

References: Oxford Online Dictionary, nine years living and teaching English in Asia, China and Korea

(On a side note, I heard this word 'alight' for the first time on a train in China. We Americans say 'get off' or 'exit' the train.)

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer! I agree that the linked blog post is difficult to understand because of the vagueness. I'm not sure if the issue was with the choice of the word "thoughtful", as the author says that "It is so thoughtful of you to queue and give way to alighting passengers" would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I might not have the prescriptivist grammarian credentials to best answer this question, but it is interesting, so here are my two cents.

The argument against "queueing is thoughtful of you" seems to rely on the idea that "[gerund] is [adjective] [preposition] you" is inherently wrong because the infinitive form should be used instead of a gerund.

> It is thoughtful of you **to queue**

therefore

> **To queue** is thoughtful of you.

But what about this counterexample:

> It is good for you **to run**.
>
> **Running** is good for you.

If being "grammatical" is connected at all to being idiomatic and observable in use, then "running is healthy for you" or "running is good for you" appear to be acceptable.  The phrases are used with only trivial variations in [*The Guardian*](https://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/the-running-blog/2016/apr/19/running-good-for-mental-health-england-athletics-ambassador-mind) and in [*The New York Times*](https://green.blogs.nytimes.com/2008/10/14/marathons-reducing-the-runners-footprint/?mcubz=0).

For what it's worth, "running is good for you" also sounds idiomatic to these native ears and probably most others.

So what's the difference between "Running is good for you" and "Queueing is thoughtful of you?"

Syntactically speaking, both follow the "[gerund] is [adjective] [preposition] you" pattern.  I can't see a reason why the OP's sentence in context would be particularly incorrect because it uses the word "of" and not "for."

Furthermore, it seems to me that a grammatically "wrong" sentence ought to be "wrong" all the time.  Would this pair of sentences be incorrect?

> Thank you for **queueing.**  **It was** thoughtful of you.

If it *is* incorrect, then would this also be incorrect?

> Thank you for **hurrying**.  It was thoughtful of you.

The latter sentence seems to have an implied ellipsis:

> Thank you for **hurrying**.  It was thoughtful of you **to hurry**.

Yet the mere fact that the ellipsed phrase takes the infinitive form doesn't seem to render the sentences *ungrammatical* or *not idiomatic*.

Based on this line of reasoning, I see no problem with the sentence "Queueing is so thoughtful of you."

Comment: Thanks. Interesting comparison to the "adj. for you" construction. I agree that '[gerund] is adj. for you" is definitely grammatical.

Comment: Maybe it is related to the following question: [Difference between a gerund acting as subject and an infinitive acting as a subject?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/177437/difference-between-a-gerund-acting-as-subject-and-an-infinitive-acting-as-a-subj). Although, I wasn't particularly thinking of the possibility of using an infinitive as a subject ... to me, the "adj. of [NP]" construction sounds best with a dummy or pronominal subject and an infintive *after* the noun phrase.

Comment: I just got to look through an older source relevant to this question, and updated my answer. While I don't think your answer is invalid by any means, I found some interesting examples indicating that "adjective for-NP" and "adjective of-NP" don't always behave alike, so I'm not sure how strong this kind of evidence is. Berman (1973) gives the following examples that contrast in grammaticality: "For whom is it easy to write a dissertation?" vs. "*Of whom was it stupid to do that?", and "the man for whom it is easy to write a dissertation" vs. "*the man of whom it was stupid to do that"

Answer (score -4):

Maybe **queueing** and not **queuing**?
Maybe this is the actual error.

From [Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/409158/is-the-sentence-queueing-is-so-thoughtful-of-you-grammatically-correct/409826?noredirect=1#comment976747_409826):

> *queue* verb [ I ] UK  /kjuː/ US  /kjuː/ UK US ***line***, US ***line up***, also UK ***queue up*** ​
>
> **2** to wait in a line of people, often to buy something:
>   *Dozens of people were queueing up to get tickets.*
>   *We had to queue for three hours to get in.* ​
>
> informal to want very much to do something: [ + **to** infinitive ]
>   *There are thousands of young women ***queueing up*** to be models.*

Comment: Spelling is not grammar.

Comment: @Andrew Leach, so a sentence with an error in spelling can be still grammatically correct?

Comment: Yes of course. A typo is merely a typo.

Comment: I don't completely agree...grammar should include syntax, the declination of verbs and correct writing of the words. It's discussed more deeply here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/388543/are-spelling-punctuation-and-capitalization-part-of-grammar. At the end, being a public advertisement, this was a nice error.

Comment: Writing *queuing* for *queueing* is not syntax, or declination. It's even following the precedent of *charge/charging*. If it is a spelling error (which I'm inclined to agree), it certainly doesn't affect the **grammar.**

Comment: Which I am inclined to agree? So you don't even agree that is a spelling error? I don't know what to think, but it looks like you have then something personal with me if even before a dictionary you state this.

Comment: No, I meant that I agree it is a spelling error. But it may be a justifiable mistake, and even though the spelling is wrong, it's only spelling. The misspelling hasn't affected the meaning or the grammar.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65531/discussion-between-ealy-and-andrew-leach).

Comment: There is a separate question about the spelling of "[queu(e)ing](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/60852/queueing-or-queuing)". Based on the quoted paragraph in the question, I don't think the blog poster was objecting to the spelling--the author says "What makes the sentence ungrammatical is its utter meaninglessness."

Comment: I agree with @sumelic here- if the author is claiming ungrammaticality due to meaninglessness then the author doesn’t understand what is covered by grammar.

Comment: If anything, the sentence provided is observant in tone, more than anything else.  The author argues that even "Queueing is so thoughtful of you." is incorrect due to the construction that "Queueing" (a gerund) cannot be paired up with the construction "so thoughtful of you" for the sake of conveying information, and so, is meaningless. I think his parsing to be incorrect, as a gerund functions as both a noun and a verb syntactically (replacing the form "to queue"). In my understanding of parsing, "Queueing is thoughtful of you." and "It is thoughtful of you to queue." are interchangeable.

Comment: I might also be biased by the fact that the author calls this actually complex English language dilemma "illiteracy" and how that makes me question just how absolutely high the author's bar for "literacy" is given that the vast majority of native English speakers would probably fall below this level of analysis and comprehension. This is absolutely notwithstanding the fact that the author could be completely wrong on this.